# Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z+i|+|z-i|=1\}$ find the set $w.D=\{wz:z\in D\}$ where $w=i$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z+i|+|z-i|=1\}$ find the set $w.D=\{wz:z\in D\}$ where $w=i$.

**My attempt**

I go to proceed to describe the set $D$.
 Let $z=x+iy$ then

$\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}=1\iff x^2+(y-1)^2=1+x^2+(y+1)^2-2\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}\iff 4(x^2+(y+1)^2)=(1+4y)^2\iff 12y^2-4x^2=3\iff 4y^"-\frac{4}{3}x^2=1$

Then, $D$ is a hiperbole.

But, now i'm stuck in the form of $w.D$ can someone help me?

Comment: Multiplication by $i$ is just a rotation by 90 degrees right?

Comment: yes @AngeloRendina... can be only a simple rotation of the hiperbole?

Answer (score 1):

the set $D$ is empty，because the distance between $i$ and $-i$ is 2.

Comment: No, the set $D$ is not empty.

Comment: From triangle inequality, $2=|i-(-i)|=|i-z+z-(-i)|\leq|i-z|+|z+i|=1$, it is contradiction.